How can I change default date format for Groovy in JMeter?
Is it anyway I can change the default date format (en_US) for JMeter and Groovy in particular? I like to avoid to use SimpleDateFormat() as it makes Groovy one liners long and hard to read.
I tried passing language and region with no luck.
jmeter -t test.jmx -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=SE

I don't believe this is OS dependent but if so I'm on MacOS and Linux (with LANG=en_SE.UTF-8).

In Groovy you don't need SimpleDateFormat, there is Date.format function.
See Groovy JDK API Documentation for any eventual enhancements on class(es) you're using or explain what exactly you're trying to achieve, it might be a better way without needing to change the Locale
For code re-use you can either use groovy.utilities property or compile helper functions and put the .class or .jar into JMeter Classpath
More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?
